# What is the Best Practice for creating a secure login in a client - server appllication?

Tags: .net, security, login

It's been a while I have been thinking on what could be the best scenario for creating a secure login in a client-server application running on internet or any other networks ! So I became with the idea to ask this question on programmers and I hope that this question will make awareness of new aspects of threads and security here by some kind of brain storming , I am really interested in good and new anseawres . Thanks in advance for your participation .

Comment: Implementing security yourself is generally a bad idea.  A good default choice is [Asp.Net Membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx), since it is: A) Included with ASP.NET, B) Well tested, and C) produced by experts.

Comment: Dear Brian ! this a a question to discuss on scenario ! I am really aware of asp.net membership !

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding.  What do you mean by 'best scenario'?  What would be an example of a bad scenario?

Answer (score 2):

Clean EVERYTHING that is inputted by the user (and even what is not). Make sure you hash/encrypt your sensitive data (i.e. passwords) -- I suggest using a salt with your password encryption.

I also suggest making it mandatory for passwords to be longer than 4 characters and have to include a number or two at least, so you don't get John Doe with the password cat ..

**Edit**
I'm not sure what language your developing in but this may be handy to get an idea on what to do .. http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL

Comment: you mean that It would be better to perform encryption or hashing on on client side and then sending the encrypted or hash data to server ?

Comment: Yes correct. Here's something more geared towards server side security, tho similar. https://www.cs.columbia.edu/~smb/classes/f06/l09.pdf

Comment: So , assuming your answear is a good way , how can I perform hashing or encryption on client side using javascript without letting the client to be aware of my encryption or hashing  algorithm ? and not letting him/her know the encrypting key ?

Comment: If It helps , I am a .net developer

Comment: @Karamafrooz: you can't.  Why would you need to do that?

Comment: @kevincline thx , I want to do that NOT to send clear text to server so prevent a packet sniffer to access the clear text ! is'nt It a good idea ? and any way to do this ?

Comment: @Karamafrooz if you dont want the communication channel to be in plain-text, use SSL.  Thats what its for.

Comment: @Karamafrooz: You didn't ask about protecting against eavesdropping.

Answer (score 2):

Don't reinvent the wheel, especially when it comes to security. If at all possible, use tried-and-tested secure login packages. There are a lot of them out there depending on what platform you are targeting.

Comment: I don' want to reinvent ! I am looking for different good SCENARIOS so that I would be able to analize them and become with a good idea ! using packages ?! not a good idea ! especially when It comes to security !

Comment: I also appreciate if you have any good scenario to share  here !

Comment: @Karamafrooz - I would disagree with you on it being unsecure. Security is *hard*. So using an existing package (preferabbly open source) that has stood the test of time is a *very* valid option for production work. I can see where you are going if what you want to do is make this a *learning* project. Still, studying successful open sourced packages is a great way to learn.

Comment: any good references you could share the link with me or something ?!

Comment: References to good packages? That depends on the platform you're targeting.

Comment: packages and scenarios  , I am a .net developer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/944944/open-source-net-authentication-libraries

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned you're a .NET programmer, be sure to take a look at Microsoft's [Introduction to Membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx).

As others have pointed out, it's better to use a package than to roll your own.